# xml cannot be resolved to a field

Tags: android, eclipse-juno

I keep getting an  error saying my xml file cannot be resolved to a field. I found answers saying to delete the import R statement which I have done, but this just brings up another error saying R cannot be resolved to a variable. It seems like I am doomed whether or not I use the import statement. Any advice?

Here's the code

```
public class VirtualGallery extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.splash);

    Handler x = new Handler();
    x.postDelayed(new SplashHandler(), 5000);   
}

class SplashHandler implements Runnable{
    public void run(){
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(VirtualGallery.this, Main.class);
        startActivity(myIntent);
    }
}
```

}

here's the splash xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#393131" >

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/museum_logo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:src="@drawable/museum_logo" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you shouldn't delete the `R.java` as it is automatically generated with out that project won't run

Comment: Have you imported YOUR R again after removing it?

Comment: Build the project again so that R.java is created again

Comment: Ensure that you Importing you project package.R not android.R

Comment: Yes I have imported R. Still no luck.

Comment: Yes Android R. How do I import the project package?

Comment: now what is the error?

Comment: Delete android.R import statement and press ctrl+shift+o and include other import statement

Comment: After the import, my splash xml file gets underlined and the error is "splash cannot be rosolved or is not a field"

Comment: where did you closed the `Relative Layout`

Comment: what is your pacakge name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have imported `your.package.R` not `android.R`.
Then look for error(s) in your `res` directory. It seems that somewhere in your `res` directory you have an error that prevents regenerating `R` class. Solve that error and `clean` your project.

Comment: how do i import the .package.R ?

Comment: in eclipse and windows, press `ctrl+shift+o` or select `source->organize imports`. It will automatically add R o your imports.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, fixed it by doing a project clean